# How to copy directories into WAR using Maven?

Tags: maven

My goal is this: I have 2 directories (not their contents but the directories themselves) which I need to get copied into both the exploded WAR directory and the packaged WAR.

Specifically, I need the following directories inside the final WAR:

- `${project.basedir}/web/WEB-INF/templates` needs to get copied into
  `target/${finalName}/WEB-INF/`
- `${project.basedir}/web/WEB-INF/classes/dao` needs to get copied to
  `target/${finalName}/WEB-INF/classes/`

So far, I haven't found any way of doing it.  I've tried the resources plugin, the war plugin's webResources feature, antrun, exec-maven-plugin, etc., and each have limitations that prevent the aforementioned directories from ending up in the final WAR.  In some cases the resultant directory structure ended up with too much nesting (e.g.: target/${finalName}/WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/classes/); in other cases nothing got copied at all, presumably because the war plugin has its own beliefs about what should and should not get copied.

As such, I'm at my wit's end.  Is there any way to copy actual directories without having the war plugin question my motives?  I wish I could tell Maven, "Do as I say!"

Comment: First you should follow the conventions and put the things you would like to have into `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates` instead of `web/..`...